# Access file in jar file?

Tags: java, file, jar

I need to be able to access a file stored in a compiled jar file.  I have figured out how to add the file to the project, but how would I reference it in the code?  How might I copy a file from the jar file to a location on the user's hard drive?  I know there are dozens of ways to access a file (FileInputStream, FileReader, ect.), but I don't know how to look inside itself.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use something like this:

`InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileFromJarFile);`

If foo.txt was in the root of your JAR file, you'd use:

`InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("foo.txt");`

assumes the class is in the same JAR file as the resource, I believe.

Comment: Part of what I need is BufferedReader which needs a FileReader as an imput.  How can I convert an InputStream to a FileReader?

Comment: You just play connect the dots with the Java documentation. Look at BufferedReader - In the See Also section, there's FileReader and InputStreamReader. Go to InputStreamReader, etc.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I just looked up BufferedReader, and found the parter class BufferInputStream which is what I need to use :P.

Comment: Interesting: ... getResourceAsStream("foo.txt"); didn't work for me, but instead getResourceAsStream("/foo.txt");

Answer (score 6):

You can use [getResource()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to obtain a URL for a file on the classpath, or [getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to get an InputStream instead.

For example:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo.txt")));
```

Answer (score 5):

You could read the contents of a JAR file using the [JarFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) class.

Here's an example of how you could get a specific file from a JAR file and extract it:

```
JarFile jar = new JarFile("foo.jar");
String file = "file.txt";
JarEntry entry = jar.getEntry(file);
InputStream input = jar.getInputStream(entry);
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
    for (int i = 0; i != -1; i = input.read(buffer)) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, i);
    }
} finally {
    jar.close();
    input.close();
    output.close();
}
```

Comment: I think what OP meant was a file within the compiled jar

Comment: @Sam1370: Yes. Doesn't this do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that if we want to access file inside Jar that is located at the following path(only examples as resources loading is OS independent):

```
Windows:  
c:\your-jar-file.jar\dir1\dir2\dir3\foo.txt

Linux: 
/home/your-jar-file.jar/dir1/dir2/dir3/foo.txt
```

Will need to use following code(pay attention that there is **NO** "/"(forward-slash) character in the beginning of the path):

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dir1/dir2/dir3/foo.txt");
```

Comment: How does getResourceAsStream know to look inside c:\your-jar-file.jar ? What if the jar file was completely separate from the jar file that the program is running from?

Comment: I just gave examples of real OS dependant paths here to understand how a resource path syntax correlate with OS absolute path. You are right that java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream only can load resources from jars that are managed by JVM you are running. I like to think of paths in their absolute form so that you can understand the most complex case it can be parsed. All this jars resources loading is handy if you want to ship jars that contain resources in them and be OS independent.

Comment: If you want to access jar file that is completely separate from JVM loaded classpath you still need to load that jar into JVM process that needs it and simplest way is to define it on the classpath. It can be loaded programmatically(https://stackoverflow.com/a/5172103/4592525) which is a different subject and is not needed in most use cases as Java does a good job for you already with its default class loader.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the JarFile class. Everything you need to get the InputStream of a specific entry in the jar file is there.