# How can i solved execute .jar?

Tags: java, jsch

Good Morning, I have a problem when I try to execute my .jar. My program read some file from distant server by JSch.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\julie\Bureau>java -jar myFile.jar 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/SftpE xception         
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)         
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)         
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)         
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)     
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException    
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)    
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)     
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)   
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)      
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)         
... 6 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing classes in this package : `com.jcraft.jsch`.

If this package come from a third part library, then make sure that the jar contais this package inside a `lib` folder at the same level of your executable jar.

**[Edit]**

**First:** to add a third part jars in eclipse:

1. Right click on your project
2. Select properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tap.
3. Select Add External JARs
4. Navigate to your jars and press OK

**Second:** to generate an executable Jar file:

1. Right click on your project
2. Select Export -> Java -> Runnable JAR File.

This should work just fine.

Comment: I added a folder lib contains my .jar at the same level of src, I exported again the .jar . When i extract the .jar, i see folder lib inside but I have de same problem,  please some idea? Help me

Comment: You don't have to add any thing, just make sure when you export the jar file, it export also the third part libraries jars.

Comment: Please salah can you give me more details. The informations (user and password) of my server are inside a file.ini and i use jsch-0.1.42.jar and jcsv-1.4.0.jar. My .jar giis not solved

Comment: Are you sure that you added this jars to your project.

Comment: I'll tell you the steps that your project should work fine. see my updated answer.

Comment: now I have a security problem, In my project there is a file .ini that contains informations (password and user) about the connexion to my server. When I extract the .jar, the file show password and user connexion. I don't want that the person who will run .jar see that information. How can i solved it?

Comment: This may help you [How to access file in jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171957/access-file-in-jar-file)

Comment: Please I want to refused Access file in jar file to user of jar.

Comment: because if the user have access, he can have password of server.

Comment: my file .ini is in my project/src

Comment: Then you need to check the current user logged in, if he one of those who have access then execute that code that access the file, else don't execute it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer of first question.