# Scan other jar files for specific line of code?

Tags: java

Let’s say I have a method called createBurger() in a jar file called 1.jar

And let’s say I want to scan for methods in another project, and scan through every jar file in a directory for “createBurger()” and return it if i find anything?

Comment: Ok, but what is the problem? It doesn't look like a question to me.

Comment: It's technically possible, but that's not a virus scanner and it's unclear what you think you will accomplish with that.

Comment: What if .jar is obfuscated?

Comment: Sorry, I meant scan for a specific line of code in all of the jar files in a specific directory.

Comment: What IDE are you using? There might be a search functionality built in. If not, you can just use `grep` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned 'line of code',
Can you please clarify what the jar files contain, either java source code or java byte code?
Usually jar files contain byte code, so in this case I'd recommend ASM.

```
ClassVisitor classVisitor = new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM7) {
    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String descriptor, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        if("createBurger".equals(name)) {
            System.out.println(access);
            // doing something
        }
        return super.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions);
    }
};
new ClassReader(inputStream).accept(classVisitor, ClassReader.SKIP_CODE | ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG | ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);
```

How to iterate java classes into a jar described here [walkFileThree inside JAR-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696255/walkfilethree-inside-jar-file)

How to iterate the jar files into the directories - see `Files.walk` or `Files.walkFileTree`