# How to access file within jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I have properties file in my application's classpath. Before creating jar file for this application there is no problem but when I create jar file and run it using `java -jar` command it returns `null pointer exception`. Here is my code to load properties:

```
private Properties loadProperties() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {
        input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("./auth");
        prop.load(input);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return prop;
}
```

Can I access property file within jar or it is not possible?

Here is exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at com.kadir.MyApp.loadProperties(MyApp.java:109)
    at com.kadir.MyApp.<init>(MyApp.java:62)
    at com.kadir.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:48)
```

and lines 108 and 109 are these:

```
    input =this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("auth");
    prop.load(input);
```

One more note: I am developing my app on Windows but running it on Linux, error may come from this

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171957/access-file-in-jar-file

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I am still getting null pointer exception

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: show your code, show stacktrace and point the line, where you get NullPointerException

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I have updated question

Comment: are you using "auth" or "./auth" as the path? also, whats the "path" for the file inside the actual jar?

Comment: where is the your file in your jar file and what is the package name of the class that has the method loadProperties?

Comment: @radai I tried both auth and ./auth but no luck. And file has same path with classpath of MyApp class

Comment: file has same path with the file MyApp.class and the package name is com.kadir @NicolasFilotto

Comment: try the full path instead this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/kadir/auth")

Comment: @NicolasFilotto still same exception

Comment: I have just tried to access a file into a jar, it could work on my side using MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/my/file") (absolute path) and MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("file") (relative path as the class and the file are both into the same folder) but it didn't work with ./file so your issue is elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason for why it wasn't working but changing these two lines

```
input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("auth");
prop.load(input);
```

to these:

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
input = classloader.getResourceAsStream("auth");
prop.load(input);
```

made my code working