# Get relative path from inside a scala library (while developing that library)

Tags: scala

I'm currently developing a scala library and wanted to get a file that is inside it, **event when compiled as a Jar dependency**. The problem is that when executed from another project where the library is imported, the path is relative to that project. Here is the code to get the file :

```
private val pathToDocker: Path = Paths.get("src", "main", "resources", "docker-compose")
```

What can I do to look for my file inside the imported dependency ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file won't be in a file system -- it'll be in the compiled JAR.

You can get a JAR resource using a class loader. Here's an example of how to do that in another codebase.

Utility function:

https://github.com/hail-is/hail/blob/6db198ae06/hail/src/main/scala/is/hail/utils/package.scala#L468

Usage to load version info:

https://github.com/hail-is/hail/blob/6db198ae06/hail/src/main/scala/is/hail/package.scala#L21

Comment: or just use `scala.io.Source.fromResource`

Comment: cool! yes, that's a better solution for projects using Scala 2.12 or later.

Comment: Actually, using fromRessource will look for the file inside the current project and not the jar dependency as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `JarUtil` - from an answer of [access-file-in-jar-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171957/access-file-in-jar-file) translate to `Scala`:

```
  import java.util.jar.JarFile

  val jar = new JarFile("path_to_jar/shapeless_2.12-2.3.3.jar")
  val entry = jar.getEntry("shapeless/Annotation.class")
  val inStream = jar.getInputStream(entry)
```

As you mentioned `scala.io.Source.fromResource` works only within your project:

`Source.fromResource("tstdir/source.txt")`

Make sure the file is in the `resources` directory, like:

[image]

Comment: Actually, using fromRessource will look for the file inside the current project and not the jar dependency as expected.

Comment: @IsmailH - sorry I missed that - see my edited answer - not as elegant - but I tested it;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @pme, I've managed to walk trough it and found a solution, I'll post an answer as son as it is validated.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to achieve getting the path inside a jar depedency was creating a singleton (scala object) that has a method that loads the files. Since it is inside the Jar, the resulting path is relative to the jar itself. Here is the code :

```
object ClassLoaderTest {   
    def dockerFile: File = 
       new File(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("docker/docker-compose.yml").getPath) 
}
```

When called from a Trait (or an interface), the resulting path is :

```
jar:file:/home/myname/.ivy2/cache/com.mypackage/libraryname/jars/libraryname.libraryversion.jar!/docker/docker-compose.yml
```