# I want to deploy the jar that include some file in classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, classpath

When I execute the jar using this command `java -jar myapp.jar`, I met the `FileNotFoundException`.

My project is a basic Gradle java application. I put the file in `ROOT/src/main/resources/testfile/test1.txt`. And I tried to run the code in IDE to check the file exists using classpath.

```java
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:testfile/test1.txt");
System.out.println(file.exists());
```

This is true, but when I executed build file that is the result of command 'gradle build', I met the FileNotFoundException. I can see the file`(\BOOT-INF\classes\testfile\test1.txt)` when I unarchive the jar.

Actually, I want to deploy the spring boot jar with the sample file and I will put the code for initializing. please help. thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171957/access-file-in-jar-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming You actually want to read the file rather than trying to address the resource use the class loader:

```java
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testfile/test1.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( in ) );
    String line = null;
    while( (line = reader.readLine() ) != null )
      System.out.println("Line: " + line);
```

that worked for me

Comment: Side note: use try-with-resources when creating local IO streams

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read the resources inside a jar as java.io.File as it says in the link that @Shailesh shared

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("classpath:testfile/test1.txt"))
```

Read the file as input stream and then may be convert it to String and then convert it to a class if needed.

Comment: the following often creates less trouble: `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/testfile/test1.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

> 'this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()' is a good choice

I meet the same question. And only difference is that I want the return type —— *String*, after reading a file.
So, I find a useful api —— `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(String name)`.

```
String read = null;
URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("static/facility-tree.json");
CharSource charSource = Resources.asCharSource(resource, Charset.defaultCharset());
read = charSource.read();
```

CharSource and Resources are from Guava, so you need to add dependency in pom.xml.

```
<!--guava->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>31.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```