# Open an inputstream for a file inside a jar

Tags: java

I want to access a file inside a jar and unmarshall it. But I cannot access it with the path as we do with the files. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the file you want to access is inside the resources folder. When you generate a jar the path changes, maybe this post would help you:
[Access file in jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171957/access-file-in-jar-file)

Comment: it is a maven dependency jar. It is located in the local maven repo. I have the path. I want to access the property file inside that jar. I want to do this for all projects in the workspace.Like Iterating through the dependencies and read properties for each. So i think that won't work.

Comment: @kiri : have you tried it? It _does work_

Comment: In my case, i am accessing the project from outside. I am not inside the project. I am doing eclipse plugin development and i am iterating through each project as IProject and get their ClassPathEntries. From that i can get the location of it. (my interested one is in the maven repo ). I tried to do as follows but didn't work.                                    
 `for (IClasspathEntry classpathEntry: classPathEntries) {    
     InputStream is = classpathEntry.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/Packages.xml");}`

Comment: This post has something similar  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do something like this.

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("the/path/of/jar");
InputStream inputStream =null;
ZipEntry file = jarFile.getEntry("file/i/need");
if(file != null) {
    inputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(file);
}
```